# Nested JSON items with scrapy

Tags: python, json, scrapy

here is my basic scrapy crawler:

```
  def parse(self, response):        
    item = CruiseItem()     

    item['Cruise'] = {}
    item['Cruise']['Cruiseline'] = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
    item['Cruise']['Itinerary'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="brochureName1"]/text()').extract()
    item['Cruise']['Price'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="interiorPrice1"]/text()').extract()
    item['Cruise']['PerNight'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="perNightinteriorPrice1"]/text()').extract()

    return item
```

This works great in pulling in all the right elements that I want. My json feed for example turns out the following:

```
[

{
    "Cruise": {
        "Cruiseline": [
            "Ship Name"
        ],
        "Itinerary": [
            "3 Night Bahamas ",
            "4 Night Western Caribbean ",
            "4 Night Bahamas ",
            "3 Night Bahamas ",
            "5 Night Western Caribbean ",
            "5 Night Eastern Caribbean ",
            "7 Night Western Caribbean ",
            "7 Night Southern Caribbean ",
            "6 Night Western Caribbean ",
            "7 Night Western Caribbean ",
            "8 Night Eastern Caribbean "
        ],
        "Price": [
            "$169",
            "$179",
            "$289",
            "$349",
            "$359",
            "$389",
            "$389",
            "$409",
            "$424",
            "$524",
            "$939"
        ],
        "PerNight": [
            "$56/night",
            "$45/night",
            "$72/night",
            "$116/night",
            "$72/night",
            "$78/night",
            "$56/night",
            "$58/night",
            "$71/night",
            "$75/night",
            "$117/night"
        ]
    }
}
]
```

The goal json output is different however:

```
[

{
    "Cruise": {
        "Cruiseline": [
            "Ship Name"
        ],
        "Itinerary": [
            "3 Night Bahamas "
        ],
        "Price": [
            "$169"
        ],
        "PerNight": [
            "$56/night"

        ]
    },
    "Cruise": {
        "Cruiseline": [
            "Ship Name"
        ],
        "Itinerary": [
            "4 Night Bahamas "
        ],
        "Price": [
            "$79"
        ],
        "PerNight": [
            "$86/night"
        ]
    }
}
]
```

Essentially i want to return each cruise line with only 1 of each ship, itinerary, price, and per night.

Does this make sense? Would love to discuss

**EDIT: asked this a few days ago, but decided to clarify and repost. Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
def parse(self, response):

    final_list = []

    item = WthItem()

    item['ship'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="shipName1"]/text()').extract()
    item['Itinerary'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="brochureName1"]/text()').extract()
    item['Price'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="interiorPrice1"]/text()').extract()
    item['PerNight'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="perNightinteriorPrice1"]/text()').extract()

    final_list.append(item)

    updated_list = []

    for item in final_list:
        for i in range(len(item['ship'])):
            sub_item = {}
            sub_item['entry'] = {}
            sub_item['entry']['ship'] = [item['ship'][i]]
            sub_item['entry']['Itinerary'] = [item['Itinerary'][i]]
            sub_item['entry']['Price'] = [item['Price'][i]]
            sub_item['entry']['PerNight'] = [item['PerNight'][i]]
            updated_list.append(sub_item)

            print sub_item

        return updated_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try re-formatting the data using this script. The formatted data will live in `updated_list`

```
cruise_list = [

{
    "Cruise": {
        "Cruiseline": [
            "Ship Name"
        ],
        "Itinerary": [
            "3 Night Bahamas ",
            "4 Night Western Caribbean ",
            "4 Night Bahamas ",
            "3 Night Bahamas ",
            "5 Night Western Caribbean ",
            "5 Night Eastern Caribbean ",
            "7 Night Western Caribbean ",
            "7 Night Southern Caribbean ",
            "6 Night Western Caribbean ",
            "7 Night Western Caribbean ",
            "8 Night Eastern Caribbean "
        ],
        "Price": [
            "$169",
            "$179",
            "$289",
            "$349",
            "$359",
            "$389",
            "$389",
            "$409",
            "$424",
            "$524",
            "$939"
        ],
        "PerNight": [
            "$56/night",
            "$45/night",
            "$72/night",
            "$116/night",
            "$72/night",
            "$78/night",
            "$56/night",
            "$58/night",
            "$71/night",
            "$75/night",
            "$117/night"
        ]
    }
}
]

updated_list = []

for cruise_obj in cruise_list:
    cruise_data = cruise_obj['Cruise']
    for i in range(len(cruise_data['Itinerary'])):
        sub_item = {}
        sub_item['Cruise'] = {}
        sub_item['Cruise']['Cruiseline'] = cruise_data['Cruiseline']
        sub_item['Cruise']['Itinerary'] = [cruise_data['Itinerary'][i]]
        sub_item['Cruise']['Price'] = [cruise_data['Price'][i]]
        sub_item['Cruise']['PerNight'] = [cruise_data['PerNight'][i]]
        updated_list.append(sub_item)
```

Some other thoughts

- If the only things being stored in your json are cruise objects, then the initial key of `Cruise` is kind of redundant
- A lot of the times, you're storing stuff in arrays that don't need to be. I'm guessing this is a scrapy problem, but you should try and modify my script a bit to remove the arrays for singular values. E.g. there shouldn't be multiple `Cruiseline`s for a cruise object. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: thanks for this, im open for trying your idea, i might need some help re-working the script however

Comment: this doesn't really help, i do not know where this updated code should be implemented

Comment: Well I can't really tell you where the code is supposed to go if I can't see your whole code base. I'm assuming `parse` is being called multiple times somewhere, as your final data so far is an array. So basically, find whatever variable your json feed is being stored in - say it's called `cruise_list`, and paste my code right after it. (My code will only work if you call your data variable `cruise_list`, so if your data variable is called `x`, do something like `cruise_list = x` right before your data is aggregated, or replace `x` with `cruise_list`

Comment: This actually worked perfectly in a regular python shell. Not sure how to implement in a scrapy spider however